# Python + Plotly: How to draw lines with multiple widths

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I wrote a program which reads a set of names, then it makes a graph.

The graph lines should be thinner or thicker based on a weight array.

My program draws+100 edges in the graph, so I need help:

`edge_x` and `edge_y` contains the information of the edge. the weight array is called `weight`.

This is the part of my code that draw the lines

```
edge_trace = go.Scatter(
    x=edge_x, y=edge_y,
    line=dict(width=0.8, color='#888'),  ### doesnt accept array width
    hoverinfo='none',
    mode='lines'
)
```

also, those lines should be in a scale of color green for example, deppending the weight.
I can't add one by one the lines in code because it should work for differente entrys. }

How can I do this?

MWE:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import networkx as nx
G = nx.random_geometric_graph(20, 0.125)

edge_x = []
edge_y = []
for edge in G.edges():
    x0, y0 = G.nodes[edge[0]]['pos']
    x1, y1 = G.nodes[edge[1]]['pos']
    edge_x.append(x0)
    edge_x.append(x1)
    edge_x.append(None)
    edge_y.append(y0)
    edge_y.append(y1)
    edge_y.append(None)

edge_trace = go.Scatter(
    x=edge_x, y=edge_y,
    line=dict(width=0.5, color='#888'),
    hoverinfo='none',
    mode='lines')

node_x = []
node_y = []
for node in G.nodes():
    x, y = G.nodes[node]['pos']
    node_x.append(x)
    node_y.append(y)

node_trace = go.Scatter(
    x=node_x, y=node_y,
    mode='markers',
    hoverinfo='text',
    marker=dict(
        showscale=True,
        colorscale='YlGnBu',
        reversescale=True,
        color=[],
        size=10,
        colorbar=dict(
            thickness=15,
            title='Node Connections',
            xanchor='left',
            titleside='right'
        ),
        line_width=2))
fig = go.Figure(data=[edge_trace, node_trace],
             layout=go.Layout(
                title='<br>Network graph made with Python',
                titlefont_size=16,
                showlegend=False,
                hovermode='closest',
                margin=dict(b=20,l=5,r=5,t=40),
                annotations=[ dict(
                    text="Python code: <a href='https://plotly.com/ipython-notebooks/network-graphs/'> https://plotly.com/ipython-notebooks/network-graphs/</a>",
                    showarrow=False,
                    xref="paper", yref="paper",
                    x=0.005, y=-0.002 ) ],
                xaxis=dict(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, showticklabels=False),
                yaxis=dict(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, showticklabels=False))
                )
fig.show()
```

actual output for my data entry

[image: how does it show with a graph]

desired output

[image: how does it should show]

Comment: You can start by including a runnable code along with a sample of your data.

Comment: you mean call another file created by this program?

Comment: No, not at all. Rather a minimal *sample* of your dataset. Or randomly produced data with an identical data *structure* so that we can help you out. Please run a quick search on how to ask a good question on SO. Doing so will increase your chances of receiving a useful answer considerably.

Comment: @vestland I have update the question with MWE. Im using the same code from plotly examples from [here](https://plotly.com/python/network-graphs/)

Comment: Perfect! Did your code snippet succesfully produce the fig in your code? A screenshot of that would improve your question too. I'll take a look when I find the time. But most likely someone of the pros will beat me to it.

Comment: @vestland done!